# Sieve of Eratosthenes in C#

Tags: c#, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Just because I've never written a real Sieve of Eratosthenes, I decided I should probably write one just to make sure I know what it is.  I'd like (constructive) criticism on best practices, potential problems, and anything else you see fit:

```
static int GetNthPrime(int n)
{
    List<int> primes = new List<int>() { 2, 3 };

    int potentialPrime = 5;

    while (primes.Count < n)
    {
        int squareRootPotentialPrime = (int)Math.Sqrt(potentialPrime);

        for (int i = 1; i < primes.Count; i++)
        {
            if (potentialPrime % primes[i] == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            if (primes[i] > squareRootPotentialPrime)
            {
                primes.Add(potentialPrime);
                break;
            }
        }
        potentialPrime += primes[0];
    }

    return primes[n - 1];
}
```

Comment: <microoptimisation> Instead of calculating the square root and doing the comparison `primes[i] > squareRootPotentialPrime`, use `primes[i] * primes[i] > potentialPrime`. `Sqrt` is definitely slower than a multiplication. </microoptimisation>

Comment: @WaiHaLee You can post that as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have written, is not exactly the Sieve of Erathostenes.
When doing the sieve, you don't do any divisions; you just step through all the numbers and cross off multiples.
The sieve doesn't find the n'th prime, but rather all primes up to a limit.
This is an example of how to do the sieve. It's a very basic version.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> SieveOfErathostenes(int upperLimit)
{
    //BitArray works just like a bool[] but takes up a lot less space.
    BitArray composite = new BitArray(upperLimit);

    //Only need to cross off numbers up to sqrt.
    int sqrt= (int)Math.Sqrt(upperLimit);
    for (int p = 2; p <= sqrt; ++p) {
        if (composite[p]) continue; //The number is crossed off; skip it

        yield return p; //Not crossed off means it's prime. Return it.

        //Cross off each multiple of this prime
        //Start at the prime squared, because lower numbers will
        //have been crossed off already. No need to check them.
        for (int i = p * p; i < upperLimit; i += p)
            composite[i] = true;
    }
    //The remaining numbers not crossed off are also prime.
    for (int p = sqrt + 1; p < upperLimit; ++p) {
        if (!composite[p]) yield return p;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calculating the square root and doing the comparison

```
if ( primes[i] > squareRootPotentialPrime )
```

use

```
if ( primes[i] * primes[i] > potentialPrime )
```

---

Taking `Sqrt` of a floating point number will definitely be slower than a multiplication of two integers.

@duffymo [states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6884381/1364007) in the answer to the SO question [c++ practical computational complexity of  SQRT()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6884359/1364007) that

> ...most library functions would calculate [`Sqrt`] using Newton's method, which converges quadratically.

**Edit**

I just realised that the integer multiplication happens *inside* the loop over existing primes, whereas the `Sqrt` happens *outside*. Once the number of existing primes reaches a threshold (I don't know when), my suggestion will be *slower* than the original. Instead, I propose the following:

```
    int squareRootLargestPrime = (int)Math.Sqrt(5);
    while ( primes.Count < n )
    {
        for ( int i = 1; i < primes.Count; i++ )
        {
            // elided

            if ( primes[i] > squareRootLargestPrime )
            {
                primes.Add(potentialPrime);
                squareRootLargestPrime = (int)Math.Sqrt(potentialPrime);
                break;
            }
```

That way you only use `Sqrt` when you get a new prime, rather than for every candidate.

---

Also, `potentialPrime += primes[0];` feels a bit strange when `primes[0]` is *always* 2.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, your code is not really a sieve.  For examples of fast, memory efficient sieves, I refer you to:

[Sieve31 for 31 bit primes, i.e. `int`.  Finds over 105 million primes.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/92366/sieve31-my-sieve-of-eratosthenes-returning-ienumerableint)

[Sieve32 for 32 bit primes, i.e. `uint`.  Finds over 203 million primes.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/92491/sieve32-a-simple-32-bit-sieve-returning-ienumerableuint-using-c)

**Constructive Comments**

A `BitArray` uses far less memory than a `List<int>`.

The `BitArray` can be even smaller by only tracking the odd numbers.

You definitely don't want to put sluggish operations, e.g. `Sqrt` inside a loop if you can avoid it.

The purpose of a sieve it to step off multiples of known prime.  Even that doesn't require multiplying as much as incrementing by that prime.  What you have is a fancier naive trial-by-division.

My [Sieve31](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/92366/sieve31-my-sieve-of-eratosthenes-returning-ienumerableint) would take around 30 seconds, returns all 105 found primes, and probably fits in a list, e.g.

```
Sieve31.Primes(int.MaxValue).ToList().
```