# Sieve32FastV2 - A fast parallel Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: c#, multithreading, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes, bitset

I’ve created a much cleaner, better designed version to my [parallel sieve](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104056/sieve32fast-a-very-fast-memory-efficient-multi-threaded-sieve-of-eratosthene).  I’ve implemented most of EBrown’s micro-optimizations but also revamped the code on my own (that is not in direct response to someone’s answer).

```
public class Sieve32FastV2
{
    private static ArgumentException BadUpperLimitException(string paramName) => new ArgumentException($"{paramName} be must greater than or equal to 2.");

    public static IEnumerable<uint> Primes(int upperLimit)
    {
        if (upperLimit < 2)
        {
            throw BadUpperLimitException(nameof(upperLimit));
        }

        return Primes((uint)upperLimit);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<uint> Primes(uint upperLimit)
    {
        if (upperLimit < 2)
        {
            throw BadUpperLimitException(nameof(upperLimit));
        }

        var instance = new Sieve32FastV2(upperLimit);
        return instance.EnumeratePrimes();
    }

    private Sieve32FastV2(uint upperLimit)
    {
        _vectors = VectorList.Create(upperLimit);
    }

    private readonly VectorList _vectors = null;

    // Performance Tweak:
    //    Favor "(number & 0x01U) == 0U" over "number % 2 == 0" or "number % 2U == 0U"
    //    Favor "x >> 1" over "x / 2"
    //    Favor "x << 1" over "x * 2" or "x + x"
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    private static bool IsEven(uint number) => (number & 0x01U) == 0;

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    private static bool IsEven(int index) => (index & 0x01) == 0;

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    private static int Halved(int value) => value >> 1;

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    private static uint Halved(uint value) => value >> 1;

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    private static int Doubled(int value) => value << 1;

    private IEnumerable<uint> EnumeratePrimes()
    {
        if (_vectors.UpperLimit < 2) { yield break; }

        yield return 2;
        if (_vectors.UpperLimit == 2) { yield break; }

        // I call _vectors[0] the rootVector not just because its the very first one, but also because
        // it was intentionally created so that the index of upperLimit's square root is contained within _vectors[0].
        var rootVector = _vectors[0];

        // Performance Tweak:  Create copy of value in local variable
        var rootBitIndex = _vectors.SquareRootIndex;

        // The number of times a bit in all BitArray(s) are accessed:
        //
        //      UpperLimit = int.MaxValue    =>   3,315,151,693 times
        //      UpperLimit = uint.MaxValue   =>   6,701,709,402 times

        for (var bitIndex = 0; bitIndex <= rootBitIndex; bitIndex++)
        {
            if (rootVector[bitIndex])
            {
                var prime = rootVector.ToNumber(bitIndex);
                yield return prime;

                // All multiples of prime - on all vectors - are composites and should be marked as such.
                MarkCompositesInParallel(prime);
            }
        }

        // Output remaining primes found beyond rootBitIndex

        // Performance Tweak:  Favor "for" over "foreach"
        for (var vectorIndex = 0; vectorIndex < _vectors.Count; vectorIndex++)
        {
            var vector = _vectors[vectorIndex];

            // Performance Tweak:  Favor "<= stopIndex" over "< vector.BitLength".  Calc stopIndex once before loop.
            var stopIndex = vector.BitLength - 1;

            // Not a performance tweak: startIndex is a separate variable just for readability.
            var startIndex = (vectorIndex == 0) ? rootBitIndex + 1 : 0;

            for (var bitIndex = startIndex; bitIndex <= stopIndex; bitIndex++)
            {
                if (vector[bitIndex]) { yield return vector.ToNumber(bitIndex); }
            }
        }
    }

    private void MarkCompositesInParallel(uint prime)
    {
        // Performance Tweak:  Favor "Parallel.For" over "Parallel.ForEach"
        Parallel.For(0, _vectors.Count, vectorIndex =>
        {
            var vector = _vectors[vectorIndex];

            // Performance Tweak:  Create copy local to lambda.  Cast once to bitStep before the inner loop.
            var bitStep = (int)prime;

            var startIndex = 0;

            if (vectorIndex == 0)
            {
                startIndex = vector.ToIndex(prime * prime);
            }
            else
            {
                var remainder = (int)(vector.StartingNumber % prime);

                // If remainder is 0, then we will use startIndex's initial value of 0.

                if (remainder != 0)
                {
                    startIndex = bitStep - remainder;

                    // On the full number scale, every other multiple of prime is even and should be skipped 
                    // over for the next multiple, which is an odd number. 
                    if (IsEven(remainder))
                    {
                        startIndex += bitStep;
                    }

                    startIndex = Halved(startIndex);
                }
            }

            // Performance Tweak:  Favor "<= stopIndex" over "< vector.BitLength".  Calc stopIndex once before loop.
            var stopIndex = vector.BitLength - 1;

            for (int bitIndex = startIndex; bitIndex <= stopIndex; bitIndex += bitStep)
            {
                vector[bitIndex] = false;
            }
        });
    }

    private class VectorList : List<Vector>
    {
        // May not slap you in the face, but these 2 properties are readonly.
        public uint UpperLimit { get; }
        public int SquareRootIndex { get; }

        public static VectorList Create(uint upperLimit)
        {
            var instance = new VectorList(upperLimit);
            instance.CreateVectors();
            return instance;
        }

        private VectorList(uint upperLimit)
        {
            // Any upperLimit > 2 should be odd for working with VectorList and Vector(s).
            if ((upperLimit > 2) && IsEven(upperLimit))
            {
                upperLimit--;
            }

            this.UpperLimit = upperLimit;
            SquareRootIndex = ToFlatIndex((uint)Math.Sqrt(upperLimit));
        }

        private void CreateVectors()
        {
            var typicalBitLength = CalcTypicalBitLength();
            var typicalNumberRange = (uint)Doubled(typicalBitLength);
            var count = (UpperLimit / typicalNumberRange) + 1;

            for (uint i = 0, endingNumber = 1; i <= count; i++)
            {
                if (endingNumber >= UpperLimit) { break; }

                // The first vector may have to be longer to accomodate the index of UpperLimit's square root.
                var length = (i == 0) ? GetSpecialFirstLength(typicalBitLength) : typicalBitLength;
                var startingNumber = endingNumber + 2;

                var vector = new Vector(startingNumber, length, UpperLimit);
                this.Add(vector);

                endingNumber = vector.EndingNumber;
            }
        }

        private int CalcTypicalBitLength()
        {
            // This is called before we have created a _vectors[0].
            var length = ToFlatIndex(UpperLimit) + 1;

            // Small enough values will result in 1 vector
            const uint smallNumberCutoff = 10000;
            if (UpperLimit < smallNumberCutoff) { return length; }

            // Divide length for later parallelization over many (but not too many) vectors.
            const int tinyFactor = 8;
            var maxVectorCount = tinyFactor * Environment.ProcessorCount;
            length = (length / maxVectorCount) + 1;

            return PaddedLength(length);
        }

        private int GetSpecialFirstLength(int length) => (SquareRootIndex < length) ? length : PaddedLength(SquareRootIndex + 1);

        private static int ToFlatIndex(uint number) => (int)Halved(number - 3);

        private static int PaddedLength(int length)
        {
            // BitArray internally uses 32 bit int[] so align upwards to a 32 bit boundary, 
            // i.e. pad the end of length (in bits) to consume a full 32 bit int.
            var remainder = length % 32;
            return (remainder == 0) ? length : length + 32 - remainder;
        }
    }

    // A Vector is aware of its bits, length, starting number, and ending number.
    private class Vector
    {
        private readonly BitArray _bits = null;

        public Vector(uint startNumber, int length, uint upperLimit)
        {
            StartingNumber = startNumber;
            var endNumber = startNumber + Doubled(length - 1);

            // In this constructor, endNumber is a long that could be > uint.MaxValue,
            // in which case we clamp the length appropriately.
            if (endNumber > upperLimit)
            {
                length = ToIndex(upperLimit) + 1;
            }

            _bits = new BitArray(length, defaultValue: true);
        }

        public bool this[int index] { get { return _bits[index]; } set { _bits[index] = value; } }

        public int BitLength => _bits.Length;

        // May not slap you in the face, but this property is readonly.
        public uint StartingNumber { get; }

        public uint EndingNumber => ToNumber(_bits.Length - 1);

        public Func<uint, int> ToIndex => (uint number) => (int)Halved(number - StartingNumber);

        public Func<int, uint> ToNumber => (int bitIndex) => (uint)Doubled(bitIndex) + StartingNumber;
    }
}
```

**Changes from Version 1**

`MarkCompositesInParallel` has been improved for better readability (more below).  The input `bitIndex` was never used so it was dropped from the method signature.  The new method has its own `bitIndex` that has no relation to the original.

I ditched the names `prime32` and `prime31`.  I want to distinguish between between a `uint` value that is Number-related and an `int` value that is Index-related.  So `prime31` was renamed `bitStep` since its really for stepping over the indices of the `BitArray`.  With that change, `prime32` is now simply `prime`.

Anywhere there is a section of code that is a performance tweak or micro-optimization, a comment is provided.

The class level field `_upperLimit` was omitted.  Instead it references the `UpperLimit` property from the private `VectorList` class.  `VectorList` also has a new property named `SquareRootIndex`.

Where appropriate, many properties and fields are now declared as `readonly`, such as `_vectors`.  For `VectorList` this would be `UpperLimit` and `SquareRootIndex`.  For `Vector` this would be `_bits` and `StartingNumber`.

`ToIndex` and `ToNumber` have been moved to the `Vector` class.  As such, I no longer have to pass a `StartingNumber` to each method.  This reduces confusion of why did I pass `3U` instead of `rootVector.StartingNumber`?  I really liked this design though it did lead to the following…

At the risk of being the tiniest bit WET, `VectorList` has a one-liner `ToFlatIndex`  function delegate that is similar to `ToIndex`.  This is both intentional and acceptable to me.  There are 2 calls to `ToFlatIndex` that are called before the first vector is ever created.

Additional tweaked methods were added.  Instead of being function delegates, I made them methods but flagged them with `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]`.  Note this requires a `using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;`.

**Performance Tweaks and Micro-Optimizations**

I implemented most of EBrown’s suggestions except for replacing `- 1` with `+ -1`.

```
// Performance Tweak:
//    Favor "(number & 0x01U) == 0U" over "number % 2 == 0" or "number % 2U == 0U"
//    Favor "x >> 1" over "x / 2"
//    Favor "x << 1" over "x * 2" or "x + x"
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private static bool IsEven(uint number) => (number & 0x01U) == 0;

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private static bool IsEven(int index) => (index & 0x01) == 0;

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private static int Halved(int value) => value >> 1;

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private static uint Halved(uint value) => value >> 1;

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private static int Doubled(int value) => value << 1;
```

The respective `IsEven` methods are referenced only once each.  Why not use them directly inline once?  Since they use micro-optimizations, I like having them grouped together and commented accordingly.  Plus later the code is more readable.

```
if (IsEven(remainder)) { }
```

is more readable than

```
if ((remainder & 0x01U) == 0U) { }
```

Other tweaks include:

- Having local copies of values, particular in a lambda.
- Using `for` rather than `foreach`.  Additionally `for` provides a
  `vectorIndex`.
- Using `<= stopIndex` rather than `< bitLength`.

For an upper limit of `uint.MaxValue`, the aggregate performance of all tweaks averaged 3.56 seconds faster over 8 timed runs.  In fact the slowest tweaked version was 2.71 seconds faster than the fastest non-tweaked version.

**MarkCompositesInParallel**

I went through 2 revisions of this.  The first was choosing better names to provide context and intent.  For instance, I renamed `targetNumber` to be `firstOddMultiple` since that’s what the target number really is meant to be.

*DRAFT VERSION*

```
private void MarkCompositesInParallel(uint prime)
{
    // Performance Tweak:  Favor "Parallel.For" over "Parallel.ForEach"
    Parallel.For(0, _vectors.Count, vectorIndex =>
    {
        var vector = _vectors[vectorIndex];

        // initialize firstOddMultiple with a default value - but validate it below.
        var firstOddMultiple = vector.StartingNumber;

        if (vectorIndex == 0)
        {
            firstOddMultiple = prime * prime;
        }
        else
        {
            var remainder = vector.StartingNumber % prime;

            if (remainder != 0U)
            {
                // CAUTION: Could this code block overflow past uint.MaxValue?
                firstOddMultiple = vector.StartingNumber + prime - remainder;

                // On the full number scale, every other multiple of prime is even and should be skipped 
                // over for the next multiple, which is an odd number.  
                if (IsEven(remainder))
                {
                    firstOddMultiple += prime;
                }
            }
        }

        // Performance Tweak:  Favor "<= stopIndex" over "< vector.BitLength".  Calc stopIndex once before loop.
        var stopIndex = vector.BitLength - 1;

        // Performance Tweak:  Create copy local to lambda.  Cast once to bitStep before the inner loop.
        var bitStep = (int)prime;

        for (int bitIndex = vector.ToIndex(firstOddMultiple); bitIndex <= stopIndex; bitIndex += bitStep)
        {
            vector[bitIndex] = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Did you notice the comment `// CAUTION: Could this code block overflow past uint.MaxValue?`

I know that `prime * prime` will not overflow but I did not work out any rigorous math based on number of processors and `tinyFactor` to conclusively say that

```
firstOddMultiple = vector.StartingNumber + prime - remainder;
```

Will not overflow.  The final version below is just as fast as the above, but the risk of overflow is mitigated.  Note that `remainder` is changed from `uint` to `int`.

*SAFER VERSION*

```
private void MarkCompositesInParallel(uint prime)
{
    // Performance Tweak:  Favor "Parallel.For" over "Parallel.ForEach"
    Parallel.For(0, _vectors.Count, vectorIndex =>
    {
        var vector = _vectors[vectorIndex];

        // Performance Tweak:  Create copy local to lambda.  Cast once to bitStep before the inner loop.
        var bitStep = (int)prime;

        var startIndex = 0;

        if (vectorIndex == 0)
        {
            startIndex = vector.ToIndex(prime * prime);
        }
        else
        {
            var remainder = (int)(vector.StartingNumber % prime);

            // If remainder is 0, then we use startIndex's initial value of 0.

            if (remainder != 0)
            {
                startIndex = bitStep - remainder;

                // On the full number scale, every other multiple of prime is even and should be skipped 
                // over for the next multiple, which is an odd number. 
                if (IsEven(remainder))
                {
                    startIndex += bitStep;
                }

                startIndex = Halved(startIndex);
            }
        }

        // Performance Tweak:  Favor "<= stopIndex" over "< vector.BitLength".  Calc stopIndex once before loop.
        var stopIndex = vector.BitLength - 1;

        for (int bitIndex = startIndex; bitIndex <= stopIndex; bitIndex += bitStep)
        {
            vector[bitIndex] = false;
        }
    });
}
```

**Misc**

At one time, the `Vector` class had

```
 public bool IsRoot => StartingNumber == 3U;
```

But as I favor `for` over `foreach` this was not needed (except when I tested a non-tweaked version that did use `foreach`).

I still have only one defined `BadUpperLimitException` but when if it gets thrown it incorporates EBrown’s suggestion of using `nameof(variable)`.

Overall the improvements did not help with performance but did lead to what I believe is a nicer design.

Comment: I was also experimenting with your previous code and with `Linq.Parallel` etc... even with `unsafe` code and pointers ;-) but I couldn't make it any faster ;-(

Comment: @t3chb0t The only sure way I can get this to run faster is to move it from my 8-core laptop and run it on a 24-core machine.