# Custom Prime Sieve

Tags: c#, primes

I've come up with a prime number finder I call the "Progressive Sieve". I wouldn't doubt it if this has already been thought of. Anyway, here is the idea, an implementation in C#, and benchmarks:

Premise: A number is prime if it cannot be divided evenly by any prime number below its square root.

Implementation:

```
static List<long> ProgressiveSieve(long bound)
    {
        List<long> primes = new List<long>() { 3 }; // start it with 3

        for (long i = 5; i < bound; i += 2) // ignore even values, because they will never be prime except 2
        {
            long sqrt = (long) Math.Sqrt(i);
            foreach (long j in primes)
            {
                if (j > sqrt) // if j gets above the square root, then i must be prime
                {
                    primes.Add(i);
                    break;
                }

                if (i % j == 0) // i is evenly divisible, no need to continue checking
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return (new List<long> { 2 }).Concat(primes).ToList(); // Because of how I start it off, I'll just add 2 here
    }
```

Benchmarks:

- `ProgressiveSieve(100,000)`: 10ms
- `ProgressiveSieve(100,000,000)`: 75102ms

Is there any room for improvement? I feel like finding the square root takes a good bit of time. More importantly, though, is the code compiling down to the most efficient IL? Are there ways I could do the exact same thing faster with optimized C#?

Comment: This isn't faster than the Sieve of Erastosthenes where using a `bound` of 104,729 takes me 3 milliseconds and a `bound` of 100,000,000 takes 1.1 seconds.

Comment: Could you post/link the code for the sieve you are using? Keep in mind, Eratosthenes' Sieve doesn't work for high numbers if you only get rid of multiples of 2, 3, 5, and 7. Some semiprimes will slip through.

Comment: Simple Sieve: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/92366/sieve31-my-sieve-of-eratosthenes-returning-ienumerableint

Comment: Parallel Sieve: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104736/sieve32fastv2-a-fast-parallel-sieve-of-eratosthenes

Comment: Your past experiences with Eratosthenes' must have been limited to very poor implementations.  My sieves in the above links work fully correct - no semiprimes slip through and all primes are accounted for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my 2nd answer to your post.  [The first answer focused on comparing it to the Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106770/custom-prime-sieve/106848#106848).  This answer will ignore Eratosthenes and just focus on your method in its own right: the coding style, what’s good, what’s bad, and areas for improvement.

**First the Good News**

Your use of braces is good and overall spacing is pleasant.  The indentation is a bit off, though.

Your casing is good as well.

**Areas of Improvement**

The worst thing the method does is create 2 lists, which adversely affects memory and performance.  There is a simple work around to this below.  Fixing this can speed things up 3X.

While `i` and `j` are iteration variables, they really could have a more meaningful name.  It’s not like `i` or `j` are indices into an array or list.  I would rename `i` to `number` and I would possibly rename `j` to `prime` … that is if I keep the `foreach` (which I don’t).

You could also use `var` where the type is clearly obvious from a simple assignment statement.   This is optional for many, since some violently oppose the `var`.

You also have no error checking, so someone could input a `bound` of -1.

**Method Signature**

I always insist on an access modifier.  Anytime I see a method without one, I immediately assume a junior developer forget it, and I’m then prone to wonder what else they may have forgotten.

As mentioned in my [1st answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106770/custom-prime-sieve/106848#106848), you probably should stick with a domain of just `int`.

It seems obvious that the return type should be `List<int>` but while internally the `primes` will be a `List<int>`, the method could equally return an `IList<int>`.

```
public static IList<int> ProgressiveSieve(int bound)
{
    if (bound < 2 || bound > int.MaxValue - 2)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(bound));
    }

    var primes = new List<int>() { 2, 3 }; // start it with 2 & 3

    for (var number = 5; number < bound; number += 2) // ignore even values, because they will never be prime except 2
    {
        var isprime = true;
        var sqrt = (int)Math.Sqrt(number);

        for (var j = 1; j < primes.Count && primes[j] <= sqrt; j++)
        {
            if (number % primes[j] == 0) // i is evenly divisible, no need to continue checking
            {
                isprime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isprime)
        {
            primes.Add(number);
        }
    }

    return primes;
}
```

**Caution Near int.MaxValue**

I check that `bound` is not too large at the top of the method.  That why I’m not worried about `number += 2` wrapping around to negatives.

One alternative would be to add an extra check in the `for`:

`for (var number = 5; number < bound && number > 3; number += 2)`

But this extra check will degrade performance somewhat.

Another alternative would be to have `number` be a `long` (but `bound` remains an `int`).  This only helps at the very high end of `int`, and may impact performance as well.

The whole caution is to ask yourself what happens if someone puts in a `MaxValue` for a number type?  What steps will you take to deal with that?

That said, Eratosthenes is still faster.

Comment: Great answer. The indentation got messed up when pasting so I didn't bother to change it. I'll definitely change `long` to `int` or `uint`, add argument checking, and start the list off with 2 as well as 3 to avoid the nasty bit at the end. That being said, I may just abandon this as a legitimate prime finder since Eratosthenes' Sieve is better.

Answer (score 3):

To the contrary, your `ProgressiveSieve` is slower than decent Sieve of Eratosthenes.  I will expand upon the why’s, which also touch on to some points made by @Dmitry.  I have seen many implementations here (and written several myself); some may be memory bloated, or code inefficient, but I have **never** seen one that lets semiprimes slip through.

**What is the Sieve’s Domain?**

As Dmitry said, you use a `long` in your method when you’ve only passed an `int` in your examples.  If you `bound` is never more than `int.MaxValue`, then your domain is `int`.  This is faster and uses less memory than working with `long`.

You could step up to `uint`.  It’s still a 32 bit value but it has twice as many primes for a `bound` of `uint.MaxValue`.  You may hit memory limitations especially since your original method requires 2 lists (thanks to the return statement at the bottom).

So you really should ask yourself what the maximum value you are concerned with, and use the type that is most efficient.  Keep in mind that if you want huge numbers, that memory becomes a concern.

**A Tale of Two Methodologies**

In a nutshell, `ProgressiveSieve`  loops over all odd numbers greater than 3 and checks if the current odd number is divisible by the current known list of primes, up to the `sqrt`.

The classical sieve of Eratosthenes implementation is to have a list of flags denoting whether an index is prime or composite.  The classical approach is to loop over every odd number starting at 3 up to the square root of `bound`.  If the current flag is composite, continue to the top of the loop.  If the current flag is prime, output that prime and then mark off multiples as composite.

Some implementations use `true` for a prime flag; others use `true` for composite flag.  Some use a `bool[]` which is faster but a memory hog; others use a `BitArray` which is slower but memory efficient.

Dmitry’s answer includes a beginner’s solution to the classical approach.  The flags are stored in a `bool[]` where a composite flag is `true` and primes are `false`.  Flags for even and odd numbers are included.  This requires 2 collections: the flags `bool[]` and the output primes `List`.  This also throws an exception for `bound` equal to `int.MaxValue`.  Plus it is memory intensive but for your example of 100,000,000 this should not be a problem.

My [`Sieve31` is an optimized approach](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/92366/sieve31-my-sieve-of-eratosthenes-returning-ienumerableint), though [@EBrown’s answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/92366/sieve31-my-sieve-of-eratosthenes-returning-ienumerableint/102000#102000) is worth a look.  I use a memory efficient `BitArray` to keep track of only the odd flags beginning at 3.  So `Sieve31` won’t throw an exception for `int.MaxValue`.  The flags use prime equal to `true` and composite equal to `false`.  I do not use 2 collections, though someone is free to use `.ToList()` outside the method.

**Comparing the Iterations**

Keep this in mind: addition is faster than multiplication which is faster than division.  I don’t know where modulo falls in there, but I’m sure it’s slower than addition.

Using a `bound` of 100 million, or what I call an `upperLimit`, let’s see how many things are going on inside the sieves.

`ProgressiveSieve` will loop over odd numbers starting at 5 up to 99,999,999.  That means iterating through the main loop 49,999,998 times, and each time through the loop requires a `Math.Sqrt`.  You will iterate over the inner loop 1,931,722,630 times.  You will hit the modulo operator 1,925,961,177 times.

`Sieve31` calls `Math.Sqrt` once.  It iterates over the first loop a mere 4999 times.  Of those, 1228 times it will be a prime and thus calculate the actual number before hitting the inner loop.  The inner loop will have 96,285,414 iterations.  The final loop will have 49,995,000 iterations.

So Eratosthenes uses less iterations, and less intense operations.

**Comparing the Memory**

Again for a `bound` of 100 million:

`ProgressiveSieve` used 110 MB until it gets to the `return` statement and needs an additional 115 MB.  This was viewed in VS 2015 Debugger.  The last `.ToList()` is also a performance drain.

`Sieve31` uses 1 MB of memory, thanks to the `BitArray`.  If I were to use a `bool[]`, this would increase the memory 6X, so 6 MB.  But the only collection kept is a set of flags, since the output is an `IEnumerable<int>`.  If one was to use a `.ToList()`, an additional 21 MB is needed.

So Eratosthenes uses less memory.

**Links with Discussions**

[Sieve31 is a simple solution](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/92366/sieve31-my-sieve-of-eratosthenes-returning-ienumerableint) using a `BitArray`.  However, [@EBrown’s answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/92366/sieve31-my-sieve-of-eratosthenes-returning-ienumerableint/102000#102000) uses a `bool[]` for faster results.  See the comments to his answer.  You may want to review my code and his code, as well as read my post.

[Sieve32](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/92491/sieve32-a-simple-32-bit-sieve-returning-ienumerableuint-using-c?lq=1) bumps it up to a uint.  You may want to read the post regarding memory usage, though you don’t have to look at the code.

[Sieve32Fast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104056/sieve32fast-a-very-fast-memory-efficient-multi-threaded-sieve-of-eratosthene?lq=1) uses parallel threads.  I do NOT recommend you look at the code, but there is good text explaining `BitArray`, performance and memory usage that is worth reading.

[Sieve32FastV2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104736/sieve32fastv2-a-fast-parallel-sieve-of-eratosthenes) is a code improvement over the above but doesn’t have any of the explanatory text.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is the `List<T>.Insert` method. You can replace

```
return (new List<long> { 2 }).Concat(primes).ToList();
```

with the following two lines:

```
primes.Insert(0, 2);
return primes;
```

---

Do you really need `long` data type? The `100,000,000` value perfectly fits into `int`.
Replacing `long` with `int` should speed up your method.

---

I've tried the classical Sieve of Erastosthenes and it seems to be **much** faster than your approach.
Please try the following method:

```
private static List<int> Sieve(int bound)
{
    bool[] a = new bool[bound + 1];

    for (int i = 2; i <= Math.Sqrt(bound); i++)
    {
        if (!a[i])
        {
            for (int j = i * i; j <= bound; j += i)
            {
                a[j] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    List<int> primes = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 2; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!a[i])
        {
            primes.Add(i);
        }
    }

    return primes;
}
```

Please see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Algorithm_and_variants) for details.
You can also use the `BitArray` class instead of `bool[]` to decrease memory consumption.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with `List.Insert()`. I'm using `long` in case I ever want to go up to much higher numbers.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your implementation is doing. Why are you using a `BitArray`? What are those loops accomplishing?

Comment: @RogueCSDev I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The implementation I was testing against was very inefficient.