# Calculate divisors using prime factorization

Tags: c#, primes, factors

For learning purpouses I wrote a class that is supposed to find all divisors for a given integer. My class makes use of primes and prime factorization to speed things up a bit.
What can I improve in my class?

Are there any microoptimiztations that could speed up the process? Any bad practices that should be avoided? I am by no means an expert at math, so feel free to be very nit-picky. :)

**DivisorFinder Class**

```
public class DivisorFinder
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The number that is searched for divisors
    /// </summary>
    private int _number;

    /// <summary>
    /// Search new divisors for a given integer
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="number">Integer that is searched for divisors</param>
    public DivisorFinder(int number)
    {
        _number = number;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Find prime numbers up to a given maximum
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="upperLimit">The upper limit</param>
    /// <returns>All prime numbers between 2 and upperLimit</returns>
    private IEnumerable<int> FindPrimes(int upperLimit)
    {
        var composite = new BitArray(upperLimit);
        var sqrt = (int) Math.Sqrt(upperLimit);

        for (int p = 2; p < sqrt; ++p)
        {
            if (composite[p])
                continue;

            yield return p;

            for (int i = p * p; i < upperLimit; i += p)
                composite[i] = true;
        }

        for (int p = sqrt; p < upperLimit; ++p)
            if (!composite[p])
                yield return p;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Search prime factors in a given IEnumerable of prime numbers
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="primesList">The IEnumerable of previously calculated prime numbers</param>
    /// <returns>IEnumerable of prime factors</returns>
    private IEnumerable<(int, int)> FindPrimeFactors(IEnumerable<int> primesList)
    {
        foreach (var prime in primesList)
        {
            if (prime * prime > _number)
                break;
            int count = 0;
            while (_number % prime == 0)
            {
                _number = _number / prime;
                count++;
            }

            if (count > 0)
                yield return ((prime, count));
        }

        if (_number > 1)
            yield return (_number, 1);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Find all divisors of the target number
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>IEnumerable of integers that divide the target without reminder</returns>
    public IEnumerable<int> FindDivisors()
    {
        var primes = FindPrimes((int) (Math.Sqrt(_number) + 1));
        var factors = FindPrimeFactors(primes);
        var divisors = new HashSet<int> {1};

        foreach (var factor in factors)
        {
            var set = new HashSet<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < factor.Item2 + 1; i++)
            {
                foreach (int x in divisors)
                {
                    set.Add((int) Math.Pow(x * factor.Item1, i));
                }
            }

            divisors.UnionWith(set);
        }

        return divisors;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var number = 2147483644;
var divisorFinder = new DivisorFinder(number);
var divisors = divisorFinder.FindDivisors();
Console.WriteLine($"Divisors: [{string.Join(", ", divisors)}]");
```

Performance for this example: ~6 milliseconds on a i5-6600K @ 3.50GHz

**Credits:**

The class was inspired by the [python example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171765/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-all-the-divisors-of-a-number) from Bruno Astrolino.

Furthermore the prime sieve function was adapted from [Dennis_E](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/82863/sieve-of-eratosthenes-in-c).

Comment: Have you done any testing for correctness or only for performance?

Comment: Be aware that Dennis_E has opdated his algorithm `SieveOfErathostenes(...)` due to a minor bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like mentioned in [Peter Taylor's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/203531/29371) you have some bugs in your code.

- The primes aren't calculated properly
- The divisors aren't calculated properly

**Let's first dig into the primes because that's the easiest.**

In the `FindPrimes()` method you are calculating the upper border like

```
var sqrt = (int) Math.Sqrt(upperLimit);
```

til which you check whether `composite[p] == false`.

This **incorrect** as it stands; you need to `+ 1` here like so

```
var sqrt = (int) Math.Sqrt(upperLimit) + 1;
```

Another problem comes with big numbers in this loop:

```
for (int i = p * p; i < upperLimit; i += p)
    composite[i] = true;
```

because if `(p * p) > int.MaxValue` it becomes negative and will run for a very loooong time (and maybe never ends). Adding a second loop condition will fix this as well.

If we take into account that all numbers divisible by `2` can't be primes, we can speed this up as well by starting the former loop at `3` and only check each second number. The same trick can be used for the last loop.

Making this a `static` method now the `FindPrimes()` method looks like so

```
private static IEnumerable<int> FindPrimes(int upperLimit)
{
    var composite = new BitArray(upperLimit);
    var sqrt = (int)Math.Sqrt(upperLimit) + 1;

    if (sqrt >= 2) { yield return 2; }

    for (int i = 4; i < upperLimit && i > 0; i += 2)
    {
        composite[i] = true;
    }

    for (int p = 3; p < sqrt; p += 2)
    {
        if (composite[p]) { continue; }

        yield return p;

        for (int i = p * p; i < upperLimit && i > 0; i += p)
        {
            composite[i] = true;
        }
    }

    if (sqrt % 2 == 0)
    {
        sqrt++;
    }

    for (int p = sqrt; p < upperLimit; p += 2)
    {
        if (!composite[p])
        {
            yield return p;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the primes will be calculated properly.

**Let us now calculate the divisors**

The main problem lies in trying to be clever. Instead of yielding a `Tuple<int, int>` let us just `yield` the single factors. We can maybe speed this up (if the compiler doesn't optimize it anyway) by calculating the upper border here as well.

Currently you have

```
    foreach (var prime in primesList)
    {
        if (prime * prime > _number)
            break;
```

to exit the loop. We can avoid the multiplication here if we once calculate the square root of `_number` and compare this with `prime` like so

```
private static IEnumerable<int> FindPrimeFactors(IEnumerable<int> primesList, int number)
{
    int upperLimit = (int)Math.Sqrt(number) + 1;

    foreach (var prime in primesList)
    {
        if (prime > upperLimit) { break; }

        while (number % prime == 0)
        {
            number = number / prime;
            yield return prime;

            upperLimit = (int)Math.Sqrt(number) + 1;
        }
    }

    if (number > 1) { yield return number; }
}
```

I have timed this and yielding single factors isn't slower than yielding a `Tuple<int,int`.

The method is now `static` as well and takes an additional parameter. After we have calculated **only** the prime factors we now need to calculate the divisors like so

```
public static IEnumerable<int> FindDivisors(int number)
{
    var primes = FindPrimes(number);
    var factors = FindPrimeFactors(primes, number);
    var divisors = new HashSet<int> { 1 };

    foreach (var factor in factors)
    {
        var set = new HashSet<int>();

        foreach (int x in divisors)
        {
            set.Add(x * factor);
        }

        divisors.UnionWith(set);
    }

    return divisors.OrderBy(d => d);
}
```

Comment: That's not a problem. The bugs are elsewhere.

Comment: @Heslacher I am not really sure, but I think the bug is not in the `FindPrimes()` method. I don't know what is causing it either tho.

Comment: @PeterTaylor and 766F6964 updated answer

Comment: 1. I repeat, calculating the "upper border" twice is not a problem. Once `FindPrimes` is fixed, `FindPrimeFactors` only needs to do trial division up to the square root, because it then recognises that whatever's left over is the last prime. 2. Yielding single divisors is less efficient than calculating their multiplicity. The bug is in the line with `Math.Pow`, but I think it's a useful exercise for OP to find it. 3. Pre-calculating the square root of `_number` can be less efficient. If you're going to do that, you should recalculate it whenever you find a factor.

Comment: 1. OK, 2. takes the same time for yielding, 3. implemented recalculating

Comment: It's not the time for yielding: it's the time for processing. Consider an input number of the form \$2^n\$. If you yield a tuple, `FindDivisors` will generate the \$n+1\$ powers thereof in \$\Theta(n)\$ time. But yielding the prime \$n\$ times makes `FindDivisors` generate the powers in \$\Theta(n^2)\$ time.

Comment: @Heslacher Thanks for you additional investigation. I am really impressed how you improved the `FindPrimes` and the `FindPrimeFactors` method. The bottleneck is the `FindDivisors` method. Most likely because of what @PeterTaylor explained. Furthermore I am a bit concered about me using `.UnionWith`. I am not aware how performant this is. Probably not the best way to create HashSets in a loop and merging them every time.

Comment: @Heslacher Okay, I managed to get it further optimized, based on your code. In the `FindDivisors` function, the primes are generated up to the number. This is what makes that so slow. We don't need this many prime numbers. Which means we can replace `var primes = FindPrimes(number);` with `var primes = FindPrimes((int) Math.Pow(number, 0.5) + 1);`. Now this is fast for larger numbers as well.

Answer (score 4):

### Bugs

`FindPrimes` is one of the better sieve implementations I've seen posted on this site, but it has an out-by-one bug. Here's some test code, which you can tidy up in a unit testing framework if you want to do things properly:

```
    var df = new DivisorFinder(72);
    int[] knownPrimes = new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47 };
    for (int limit = 1; limit <= 50; limit++)
    {
        var expected = knownPrimes.Where(p => p < limit);
        var observed = df.FindPrimes(limit);
        if (!expected.SequenceEqual(observed)) Console.WriteLine($"Error for limit {limit}");
    }
```

---

`FindDivisors` has a more alarming bug. What are the divisors of `72`? According to this code, they include `144`...

---

### Structure

`FindPrimes` should be `static`: nothing in that method depends on instance fields or properties.

`FindPrimeFactors` modifies state, so it's not idempotent. Calling `FindDivisors` twice on the same object should give the same results, but it doesn't.

Frankly, this class is an example of OO purism at its worst. There's no good reason for *any* of the methods to be non-`static`.

---

IMO the dependency relationship between `FindDivisors` and `FindPrimeFactors` is wrong: `FindPrimeFactors` should be responsible for calculating which primes it needs to use. Consider that if you want to have multiple methods which use the prime factors in different ways, you shouldn't have to copy-paste the line

```
    var primes = FindPrimes((int) (Math.Sqrt(_number) + 1));
```

into every single one.

Comment: I thought I got some strange values but didn't dig into it further. If I could I would give you +10 ;-)

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks for your reply. I wasn't aware of this critical bug. I am not entirly sure yet what triggers this behaviour. Apparently the wrong divisor is always twice the original number, so it seems. 
Regarding your structure suggestions: `FindPrimeFactors` would not have an `IEnumerable<int>` with the primes as parameter but instead only the target number which is then passed to a `FindPrimes` call from inside the `FindPrimeFactors` method?
And yes I agree all method can actually be made static. The target number can be provided as parameter to the `FindDivisors` method.

Comment: @766F6964, that is indeed what I meant about `FindPrimeFactors`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I was thinking if it would be even better to make the PrimeFinder a seperate, also static, class. Mainly Because finding divisors and finding primes are two separate things.